# Change $this to different block in related.phtml

Tags: configurable-product, class, custom-block, related-products

I am working in `related.phtml` in `app/design/frontend/[package]/default/template/catalog/product/list/`. Here there is a `foreach` loop: `<?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>` which loops through and outputs the related items of the main product on the page.

I have modified the contents of the loop to display the drop-down configurable options for each related product (if it is a configurable product). 
See image below: 
[image: Configurable Related Products]
Unfortunately, the `<option>`'s in the `<select>` drop-downs do not have any `value` attribute, so when the form is submitted, they have no effect.

The code from `configurable.phtml` found in `app/design/frontend/[package]/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/` which loads the configurable options for the main product on the page, uses these lines which runs some JavaScript to add the `value`'s:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $_jsonConfig ?>);
</script>
```

But adding this directly to my code in `related.phtml` doesn't have any effect and would probably conflict with the main product, as suggested [here](http://inchoo.net/magento/display-multiple-configurable-products-with-options-on-one-page-in-magento/). I have followed their advice and used this code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var spConfig_<?php echo $_item->getId()?> = new Inchoo_Product.Config(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
 </script>
```

and made a new namespace with the `product.js` as suggested, but still this has no effect, and the `<option>`'s still have no `value` attribute.

I think the issue is with the `$this` in the above code, because it is pointing to the wrong `class`, because this code was originally intended for `configurable.phtml` NOT `related.phtml`.

**So my question is, how do I change where `$this` is pointing?**

Answer (score 3):

In the context of any given block, $this is defined as the block type so in your theme or module definition layout updates, you would need to update the block type to point to the correct block.

`<block type="sales/order_info" as="info" name="sales.order.info"></block>`

This is an example block from the Mage_Sales module so when that blocks being rendered, the context of $this should resolve to Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Info.

`<block type="module/block" as="info" name="sales.order.info"></block>`

Updating to the above, asuming it should now look for the handler of module, which we shall assume was defined in Your_Module, and look for the block "block"

Your_Module_Block_Block

Hope that makes helps.

Comment: Yes, I do need to change the block to a different one, but I cannot change the block `related.phtml` points to because other code in `related.phtml` relies on the block being as it already is. So is it possible to change the block after that code, like halfway through?

Comment: In that case you have two options: extend the block you are relying upon functionality from and implement your requirements into the new block then update, this way will keep the functions you are relying on. Alternatively, configure it so that your custom requirements are implemented as a child block.

Answer (score 3):

As John pointed out `$this` references the block object in Magento itself. All templates are rendered with a block. But I want to give you a little more information:

### Block types

There are two main types of blocks - those that utilize a template and those that do not.

All template rendering block types inherit from `Mage_Core_Block_Template` and all others inherit from `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract` directly.

Other types of blocks exist as well, such as `Mage_Core_Block_Text` which uses the value set by the `setText` method for output.

### Rendering a block

A block is rendered when you echo the block's `toHtml` method. E.g.:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('child.block.name')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Magento has a few ways of creating blocks:

- Layout XML
- PHP

Both of those methods are valid and both are used in Magento for different purposes.

### "Changing" the block type

And now to answer your *real* question. Generally if you want to *change* which block is handling your template's rendering you'll want to unset or remove the existing block.

```
<remove name="my.block"/>
```

OR:

```
<reference name="content">
    <action method="unsetChild"><name>my.block</name></action>
</reference>
```

**Which one do you use?** If you're merely relocating a block you'll want to unset it because the block isn't destroyed. You can still insert it elsewhere later. If you want to **reset its type** you'll want to `remove` it.

**So we'll use remove**.

```
<remove name="my.block"/>
```

Then all that's left to do is to recreate the block with our new custom type:

```
<block type="my/related" name="my.block" template="original/template/to/render.phtml" />
```

How does it know what `my/related` is?

### Creating your new block class

You'll need to make a new block class. But we **don't need to reinvent the wheel!** We can inherit from the block class we're attempting to rewrite. For your example:

```
        <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" before="-" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
```

The original block is `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Related`.

You'll want to inherit from that, then, in the creation of your new block:

```
class My_Module_Block_Related extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Related
```

For more information on creating your own blocks visit this blog:

https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magebridge/administration/600-adding-a-custom-magento-block